# Sequelize - Update row where col = dynamic variable

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible with Sequelize to dynamically select a column with a variable?

For example :

I have a table (schedule) with the days as column (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, ...) where I store hours of work.

I would like to select the column that corresponds to the request of my client (client side I return a day (string) and with this day I must select the correct column and modify it.I can select the column with

```
coach.getSchedule({
            attributes: [dateToLowerCase]
        })
```

But impossible to modify, I tried this:

```
                // schedule.set(day, hoursString)
```

But impossible to save, it returns an error

EDIT :

Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Schedule = sequelize.define('Schedule', {
    start_date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    end_date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    monday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    tuesday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    wednesday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    thursday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    friday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    saturday: DataTypes.STRING(24),
    sunday: DataTypes.STRING(24)
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });
  Schedule.associate = function (models) {
    Schedule.belongsTo(models.Coach, {
      foreignKey: 'fk_id_coach'
    })
  };
  return Schedule;
};
```

Controller:

```
exports.updateCoachSchedule = (req, res) => {
const coachId = req.body.coachId
const day = req.body.day;
const indexArray = req.body.indexArray;
Coach.find({
    where: {
        id: coachId
    }
}).then((coach) => {
    if (!coach) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: "Coach inexistant"
        })
    }
    dateToLowerCase = day.toLowerCase();;

    coach.getSchedule({
            attributes: [dateToLowerCase]
        }).then(schedule => {
            if (!schedule) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Pas d\'horaire.'
                })
            }
            const stringRetrieved = schedule.dataValues
            const chainOfStringSchedule = stringRetrieved[Object.keys(schedule.dataValues)[0]]
            hours = transformChainSchedule(chainOfStringSchedule)

            for (var i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
                hours[i] = indexArray.includes(i) ? "1" : "0";
            }

            const hoursString = hours.join("")



            schedule.set(day, hoursString).save().then(() => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Schedule modified !",
                    schedule

                })
            }).catch(err => {
                res.json({
                    err
                })
            })



        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })
})
```

}

Thank you !

Comment: Whats the value you are passing in `schedule.set(day, hoursString)` ?

Comment: @Vivek Doshi, the value day = my request(example:monday) , and hoursString = a chain of strings "hoursString": "001111000010100000000000". it is 24 characters representing the hours of a day (0 = closed time, 1 = open time)

Comment: Getting any error with that ? if no please post the raw query generated by that line.

Comment: If I console.log(schedule) after schedule.set(day, hoursString), schedule is modified, but the error occurs when I have to save it in the db
The response of postman is : error{}

Comment: `Executing (default): SELECT `monday` FROM `Schedule` AS `Schedule` WHERE `Schedule`.`fk_id_coach` = 1 LIMIT 1;
POST /api/admin/coach/schedule/update 500 25.507 ms - 12`

Comment: Will you please post whole block of code , I am not getting how the flow is going , where are you getting `schedule` and other things.

Comment: See Edit @Vivek Doshi please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178435/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-miguelit0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
schedule.set(day, hoursString).save().then()
```

Use the below one , this will solve your issue ,

```
let updateData = {};
updateData[day] = hoursString;
schedule.update(updateData).then()
```

Comment: Thank you much, this solved my problem. Just add 'id' on attributes when I get schedule.